# Comparing two strings C++

Tags: c++, string

Can you compare two strings simply by putting `string1==string2`?

```
void ex_file_licensing::compare_license(const std::string &reference,
                                        const std::string &result)
{
    if (reference == result)
        cout << "It's the same" << endl;
    else 
        cout << "It's diffrent" << endl;
    return;
}
```

If yes will this code work properly or should I make some modifications.

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on what notion of string equality you want to test for. If you want to check if the contents are byte-to-byte identical, then yes, it's the right way to test if the strings are equal.

Comment: +1. @Fanael - could you comment on what other notions of string equality might be, and whether `==` tests for those?

Comment: @Robᵩ: for example, glyph equality (e.g. `latin small letter a with diaeresis` and `latin small letter a` + `combining diaeresis` both represent the same glyph, but their encodings are vastly different). `==` tests only for byte-to-byte equality, unless you implement your own `char_traits`.

Comment: @Robᵩ: Case-insensitive equality?

Answer (score 6):

Yes. Yes.

Just trying compiling, run, and see yourself.

The class `std::string` has overloaded `operator==` which is why it will work.

Comment: it won't work. \xcc\x88 ( ̈ + a ) and \xc3\xa4 (ä) are the same glyph, but ```==``` thinks they are different.